# Unir 3 condiciones en composer

Tags: composer

Hola(: Me gustaria poder recibir ayuda para unir 3 condiciones en composer.
Tenia una sola condición que no funcionaba bien entonces hice 3 pero no se como podria unirlas para que escoga entre las 3 opciones:

Esta era la condición que no funcionaba bien ya que si no habia dia o mes me daba null todo en lugar de darme solo el año o solo el año y el mes:

```
choose (
when isValue ($i_concstart_y) then
parseDate(toISODate($i_concstart_y,
choose (when  $i_concstart_m == "JAN" then 01
when $i_concstart_m == "FEB" then 02
when $i_concstart_m == "MAR" then 03
when $i_concstart_m == "APR" then 04
when $i_concstart_m == "MAY" then 05
when $i_concstart_m == "JUN" then 06
when $i_concstart_m == "JUL" then 07
when $i_concstart_m == "AUG" then 08
when $i_concstart_m == "SEP" then 09
when $i_concstart_m == "OCT" then 10
when $i_concstart_m == "NOV" then 11
when $i_concstart_m == "DEC" then 12
when responseCodeOf($i_concstart_m) == "UNK" then null),
choose (when responseCodeOf($i_concstart_d) == "UNK" then null 
otherwise $i_concstart_d)),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Entonces hice estas tres condiciones pero al unirlas con choose las 3 me sale error

Estas son las 3 separadas:

```
choose (
when isValue ($i_concstart_y) then
parseDate(toISODate($i_concstart_y,
choose (when  $i_concstart_m == "JAN" then 01
when $i_concstart_m == "FEB" then 02
when $i_concstart_m == "MAR" then 03
when $i_concstart_m == "APR" then 04
when $i_concstart_m == "MAY" then 05
when $i_concstart_m == "JUN" then 06
when $i_concstart_m == "JUL" then 07
when $i_concstart_m == "AUG" then 08
when $i_concstart_m == "SEP" then 09
when $i_concstart_m == "OCT" then 10
when $i_concstart_m == "NOV" then 11
when $i_concstart_m == "DEC" then 12),
choose (when $i_concstart_d then $i_concstart_d)),"yyyy-MM-dd")),

choose (
when isValue ($i_concstart_y) then
parseDate(toISODate($i_concstart_y,
choose (when  $i_concstart_m == "JAN" then 01
when $i_concstart_m == "FEB" then 02
when $i_concstart_m == "MAR" then 03
when $i_concstart_m == "APR" then 04
when $i_concstart_m == "MAY" then 05
when $i_concstart_m == "JUN" then 06
when $i_concstart_m == "JUL" then 07
when $i_concstart_m == "AUG" then 08
when $i_concstart_m == "SEP" then 09
when $i_concstart_m == "OCT" then 10
when $i_concstart_m == "NOV" then 11
when $i_concstart_m == "DEC" then 12),
choose (when responseCodeOf($i_concstart_d) == "UNK" then null)),"yyyy-MM")),

choose (
when isValue ($i_concstart_y) then
parseDate(toISODate($i_concstart_y,
choose (when  $i_concstart_m == "JAN" then 01
when $i_concstart_m == "FEB" then 02
when $i_concstart_m == "MAR" then 03
when $i_concstart_m == "APR" then 04
when $i_concstart_m == "MAY" then 05
when $i_concstart_m == "JUN" then 06
when $i_concstart_m == "JUL" then 07
when $i_concstart_m == "AUG" then 08
when $i_concstart_m == "SEP" then 09
when $i_concstart_m == "OCT" then 10
when $i_concstart_m == "NOV" then 11
when $i_concstart_m == "DEC" then 12
when responseCodeOf($i_concstart_m) == "UNK" then null),
choose (when responseCodeOf($i_concstart_d) == "UNK" then null)),"yyyy"))
```

Quiero unirlas en una sola para que escoga entre las 3 condiciones